# Is MonoGame Pipeline Tool not included anymore in the Visual Studio MonoGame NuGet Package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, monogame

so I am currently trying to make a game in **Visual Studio (C#) with MonoGame**, but the MPT does not open when I try to double-click the **Content file in Content Folder**. As I watched pretty recent tutorials, everyone worked with Pipeline and had *no problems* after using the NuGet. In the Content folder I only got the *'obj'* folder and the *Content.mgcb* file.[See How Content File Shows In Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUtoX.png)

So yeah, I saw that some people figured it out by *right-clicking the file* and *'open with...'* and then The MonoGame Pipeline Tool option would show up. I heard that there's this thing, **MGCB Editor** out. Is it a replacement for Pipeline? What should I do to get Pipeline?

PS: I am using the latest version of Mono, 3.8.0

Comment: What the full name of the nuget package `MonoGame` are you using? Also, what the type of your project, `net core 3.1` or `net framework 4.7.2`? And what nuget management format are you using, `packages.config` or `PackageReference`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actually**, MonoGame Pipeline Tool is contained into the nuget package [dotnet-mgcb-editor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-mgcb-editor/).

**And** so far, **The Team** has changed to use that one. [The old one's instruction is here](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/blob/master/Docs/CocosSharp/content-pipeline/walkthrough.md#:%7E:text=Now%20that%20we%20have%20a,Android%5CAssets%5CContent%5C.).

> I heard that there's this thing, MGCB Editor out. Is it a replacement
> for Pipeline? What should I do to get Pipeline?

Yes. It is a replacement for `MonoGame Pipeline Tool` now and it is used currently.

**Before** installing such tool, you should install [Net Core 3.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) and it requires that.

**To** install the tool, you should open CMD to install that package, call these:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-mgcb-editor
```

And it will install the tool from the nuget package under

```
C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.dotnet\tools\mgcb-editor.exe
```

**And** you can use it there and also you can call it from CMD directly.

**Besides**, I think the nuget package [MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task 3.8.0.1641](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task/) is possible and if it does not meet your requirements, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what had to be done. After I installed the MGCB Editor I could finally find the .exe and set it as default. It was quite a pain to search this up, but thanks to people like you, I could finally get back to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\username\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-mgcb-editor\3.8.0.1641\dotnet-mgcb-editor\3.8.0.1641\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\mgcb-editor-wpf.exe
```

After installing the tool as per accepted answer, double clicking on Content.mgcb inside visual studio still didn't work. Associating the .mgcb extension with the above file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this piece of code in my CMD after to the accepted answer and I was able to launch it from with VS.

First run this as in the accepted answer:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-mgcb-editor
```

Then this

```
mgcb-editor --register
```